# Is $f(S) = (\mathbb{N} \setminus A)$ surjective or injective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Based on [Cantor's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) for any set $A$ there is no surjective function $A\to\mathcal P(A)$. How about $\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(A)$? For instance, if $\mathcal P(\mathbb{N})\to \mathcal P({\mathbb{N}})$, where $\forall S \in P(\mathbb{N}): f(S) = (\mathbb{N} \setminus S$) then is *f(S)* surjective or injective? I think:

1. It is surjective since for every element of co-domain $\mathcal P(A)$, there is an element from domain $\mathcal P(A)$ to be mapped to.
2. It is injective since for any two different inputs from domain, the corresponding outputs are not the same.

But I don't know how to prove each of them, if my claims are correct.

**Note**: "$\setminus$" denotes difference i.e. $A \setminus B = \{x | (x \in A) \wedge (x \not\in B)\}$

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{N}\setminus S$? If so, yes, this works! Even easier: the identity function $\mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(A)$ is always surjective.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Yes it was a typo, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep -- this is definitely both injective and surjective. A simpler example of an injective and surjective function on $\mathcal P(A)$ is $f(S)=S$.

A cool way to prove this is using that $f(f(S))=S$, which you can prove by showing that both sides contain exactly the same elements. From this,

1. For every $S$, there exists $T$ for which $f(T)=S$ (take $T=f(S)$), so $f$ is surjective.
2. If $f(S_1)=f(S_2)$, then $S_1=f(f(S_1))=f(f(S_2))=S_2$, so $f$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you, nice and concise explanation.

Comment: Just one question, in your answer do you mean that $f(S) = (\mathbb{N} \setminus A)$ is literaly the same as $f(S) = S$ or similar to $f(S) = S$? Since $f(S) = (\mathbb{N} \setminus A)$ returns the complement of _S_ out of $\mathbb{N} $, right?

Comment: @Coder The two functions $f(S)=\mathbb N\setminus S$ and $f(S)=S$ are both injective and surjective functions on $\mathcal P(A)$, but they are different. I've updated my answer to clarify this.